# Type error in the update function in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm new to elm (0.17) and I try to understand how it works. In this case, I try to develop a kind of project estimation. 
This is what I did:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App as Html
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)

import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- model
type alias Host = {
  name : String,
  cost : Int
}
type alias Model =
  { email : String
  , hosting : List Host
  , period : List Int
  , interventionDays : List Int
  , total : Int
  }

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (Model "init@email.fr" [{name="AAA", cost=15}, {name="BBB", cost=56}, {name="CCC", cost=172}] [1..12] [1..31] 0, Cmd.none)


type Msg = Submit | Reset

calculate : Int
calculate = 42 -- to test

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update action model =
  case action of
    Submit ->
      (model, calculate)
    Reset ->
      (model, Cmd.none)

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.none


-- view
hostOption host =
  option [ value (toString host.cost) ] [ text host.name ]

durationOption duration =
  option [value (toString duration) ] [ text (toString duration)]

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  Html.form []
    [ h2 [] [ text "Estimate your project"]
    , input [ placeholder model.email ] []
    , select []
      (List.map hostOption model.hosting)
    , select []
      (List.map durationOption model.period)
    , select []
      (List.map durationOption model.interventionDays)
    , Html.span [][text (toString model.total)]
    , button [onClick Submit] [text "Submit"]
    , button [onClick Reset] [text "Reset"]
    ]
```

I think I have understood some ideas behind elm but I need help because elm-make command returns:

```
The 1st and 2nd branches of this `case` produce different types of values.

40|   case action of
41|     Submit ->
42|       (model, calculate)
43|     Reset ->
44|>      (model, Cmd.none)

The 1st branch has this type:

    ( a, Int )

But the 2nd is:

    ( a, Cmd a )

Hint: All branches in a `case` must have the same type. So no matter which one
we take, we always get back the same type of value.

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

I understand the problem but I do not know how to fix it. Do I have to define my calculate function to work with model data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you want to update the the `total` field of your model with `calculate`.

The first tuple item that the `update` function returns is the updated model. As things stand, both of your actions return the existing model without changing it. So you could try this:

```
case action of
  Submit ->
    ({ model | total = calculate }, Cmd.none)
  Reset ->
   init
```

See [here](http://elm-lang.org/docs/records#updating-records) for the syntax for updating records.

Note that I also changed the Reset branch to return `init`, the initial model and command.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is telling you that the update method, in some cases will return a `(Model, Cmd)` tuple, and in another cases will return a `(Model, Int)` tuple.

The update function as you have it, should return the modified model and also a Cmd to execute an action, in other words, a `(Model, Cmd)` tuple.

If you return `(model, calculate)` it will return a `(Model, Int)` tuple, since `calculate` is an `Int`. That is what is breaking the compiling.

So to fix it, first you need to decide what to do with each of the Msg. I assume by the name of them that the `Calculate` Msg will update the total and the `Reset` Msg will set the model to the default state.

For that you could do:

```
    case action of
       Submit ->
          ({ model | total = calculate }, Cmd.none)
       Reset ->
          init
```

In this case, both branches will return a tuple of type `(Model, Cmd)`.

Note that the `Reset` branch will return `init`, which is already of type `(Model, Cmd)`.

Check the official guide for more examples: http://guide.elm-lang.org/index.html